# How to deal with Cancel Character in a string?

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, http-headers, hex

I have a string coming into our service which we add it in the `Http Header` (as key value pair) and then we make http call using `PostAsync` method of `HttpClient`.

Before we add that string in the http header we encode it using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` utility as it can contain Non-Ascii characters. Everything was working fine with this encoding utility until today. Today I saw a weird string coming into our services and after debugging, it looks like it has a cancel character in it. Below is the string coming into our service -

[image]

And below is how we use it in our code:

```
string temp = "weird-string-coming";
foreach (char c in temp)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("char: 0x{0:X}", (int)c));
}
string encodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(temp);
// Now add this encoded string into http header
// make http call here
```

And I printed out the Hex values of each of those character in the string and they looked like this -

```
char: 0x68
char: 0x65
char: 0x6C
char: 0x6C
char: 0x6F
char: 0x3B
char: 0x94
char: 0x77
char: 0x6F
char: 0x72
char: 0x6C
char: 0x64
char: 0x3B
char: 0x94
```

So from the above output I can see `0x94` is a cancel character. Now for some reason `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` didn't do anything on that cancel character while encoding so it got added in `Http Header` as it is (without any change) and then `PostAsync` method of `HttpClient` threw exception -

```
Request headers must contain only ASCII characters.
```

So my confusion is -

- Why `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` didn't do anything on that cancel character?
- Also how should I fix this in the code properly so that it can handle this scenario? Do I need to encode this differently?

Comment: umm... `HtmlEncode` produces an HTML encoded string (replacing `<` with `&lt;` for example). You are not supposed to use it to remove non-ASCII characters...

Comment: Didn't you ask this earlier today?

Comment: Lets take a step back.... so if you get a string with crud in it, do you want to send that string and encode it some how, try and clean it up, make it magically work, strip out all the non ascii characters, replace all control characters with a smiley face?

Comment: You are probably using the wrong method. How about using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` instead?

Comment: I don't need to remove any characters. I am just  trying to encode string (coming into our service) so that I can send it via http header over network and then receiver can decode it back if needed and use it whatever they want to. So I thought to use `HtmlEncode` here. Isn't the right way to do that? Can you pls explain why I am using wrong method? @thehennyy

Comment: `HtmlEncode` is probably wrong here because you are not dealing with html, also obviously it does not solve your problem. Using url encoding will encode all characters that will have special meanings into a form that is allowed in http headers. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.6.

Comment: yeah it works now. That's a good catch. Thanks for helping me out here. I didn't realize I was using wrong method. Just trying to understand more what's the difference between `HtmlEncode` vs `UrlEncode` here? @thehennyy